# java.sql.SQLDataException: No such column: 2

Tags: java, mariadb, maven, intellij-idea

me gustaría que me ayuden con esta duda que tengo sobre una excepción en particular, bueno tengo este método:

```
    public static Reader getReader(String code){
    Reader r = new Reader();
    try {
        openConnection();
        query = connection.prepareStatement("select people_tbl.id_people,\n" +
                "\tpeople_tbl.dni,\n" +
                "\tpeople_tbl.first_name,\n" +
                "\tpeople_tbl.last_name,\n" +
                "\tpeople_tbl.number_phone,\n" +
                "\tpeople_tbl.sex,\n" +
                "\tpeople_tbl.birthday,\n" +
                "\tpeople_tbl.address,\n" +
                "\tpeople_tbl.email,\n" +
                "\tpeople_tbl.password,\n" +
                "\tpeople_tbl.is_staff,\n" +
                "\tpeople_tbl.is_active,\n" +
                "\tpeople_tbl.is_superuser,\n" +
                "\tpeople_tbl.date_register,\n" +
                "\treader_tbl.code_reader,\n" +
                "\treader_tbl.occupation \n" +
                "from people_tbl inner join reader_tbl\n" +
                "on people_tbl.id_people =reader_tbl.id_reader\n" +
                "WHERE code_reader=?");
        query.setString(1,code);
        result = query.executeQuery();

        if(result.next()){
            r.setIdPeople(result.getInt(1));
            r.setDni(result.getString(2));
            r.setFirstName(result.getString(3));
            r.setLastName(result.getString(4));
            r.setNumberPhone(result.getString(5));
            r.setSex(result.getString(6).charAt(0));
            r.setBirthday(result.getDate(7));
            r.setAddress(result.getString(8));
            r.setEmail(result.getString(9));
            r.setPassword(result.getString(10));
            r.setStaff(result.getBoolean(11));
            r.setActive(result.getBoolean(12));
            r.setSuperuser(result.getBoolean(13));
            r.setDateRegister(result.getDate(14));
            r.setCodeReader(result.getString(15));
            r.setOcupation(result.getString(16));
            return r;
        }

    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        closeConnection();
    }
    return null;
}
```

El detalle es que ocurre un excepción cuando la coloco la creación del objeto Reader debajo de condicional, tengo dudas sobre por que ocurre eso, puesto que recuerdo haberlo hecho así antes.

Tecnologias que utilizo, OpenJDK 11 y MariaDB.

```
        if(result.next()){
            Reader r = new Reader();

            r.setIdPeople(result.getInt(1));
            r.setDni(result.getString(2));
            r.setFirstName(result.getString(3));
            r.setLastName(result.getString(4));
            r.setNumberPhone(result.getString(5));
            r.setSex(result.getString(6).charAt(0));
            r.setBirthday(result.getDate(7));
            r.setAddress(result.getString(8));
            r.setEmail(result.getString(9));
            r.setPassword(result.getString(10));
            r.setStaff(result.getBoolean(11));
            r.setActive(result.getBoolean(12));
            r.setSuperuser(result.getBoolean(13));
            r.setDateRegister(result.getDate(14));
            r.setCodeReader(result.getString(15));
            r.setOcupation(result.getString(16));
            return r;
        }
```

```
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/fasstiSoft/.var/app/com.jetbrains.IntelliJ-IDEA-Community/cache/tmp/
java.sql.SQLDataException: No such column: 2
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.com.read.resultset.SelectResultSet.checkObjectRange(SelectResultSet.java:628)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.com.read.resultset.SelectResultSet.getString(SelectResultSet.java:943)
    at com.fasstisoft.models.Reader.getReader(Reader.java:197)
    at com.fasstisoft.controllers.CReader.getReader(CReader.java:14)
    at com.fasstisoft.library.Library.main(Library.java:14)
```

Debo decir que la clase Reader es una clase hija de la Clase People, los atributos de la clase padre son protected, he pensado que tal vez sea por eso, pero la verdad los cambie a privados y es el mismo error. Ante todo muchas gracias por la respuesta.

Comment: Bienvenido a SOe. Deberías indicar cuál es la línea en que te lanza la excepción.

Comment: Segun el IDE es en la linea:  `r.setDni(result.getString(2));`